# What does (long) and double inferior mean in java

Tags: java, biginteger

I want to understand what this java line code does , especially (long) and <<7

```
  BigInteger x = BigInteger.valueOf(((long) sourceArray[0]) << 7);
```

If it's possible how to write it in R

Thanks

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(long)` is casting the value of `sourceArray[0]` from the array's type into a `long` value.

In java the `<<` operation is a bitwise manipulation operation. This means that the base 2 version of `sourceArray[0]` is going to be "left shifted" 7 times. You can check out this link for more information on bitwase operations: [Bitwise operations](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_basic_operators.htm)